# Bcrypt Invalid Hash in rspec while testing if user should hash a user's password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, bcrypt, password-encryption

Let me know what to fix in the model or rspec so that the test can successfully encrypt and decrypt passwords from the database level

I initially tried using `has_secure_password` and explicit `def password=(password)` methods but in the User model class I now have a save callback to `encrypt_password` and `clear_password` which waves away the plaintext after DB is updated

following is the schema, model & rspec test:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password_digest
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    include BCrypt
    
    attr_accessor :username, :password
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
    validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

    before_save :encrypt_password
    after_save :clear_password

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
        end
    end

    def clear_password
        self.password = nil
    end

end
```

```
require 'rails_helper'
include BCrypt

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
    it "should hash a user's password" do 
        @user = User.new
        @password = Password.create("my grand secret")
        @password = "my grand secret"
        @user.password

        # store it safely
        @user.update_attribute(:password, @password)

        # read it back
        @user.reload
        @db_password = Password.new(@user.password)

        # compare it after retrieval
        expect(@db_password).to eql("my grand secret")
        expect(@db_password).to_not eql("a paltry guess")
    end
end
```

```
Failures:

  1) User should hash a user's password
     Failure/Error: @db_password = Password.new(@user.password)

     BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash:
       invalid hash
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.19792 seconds (files took 0.56839 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5 # User should hash a user's password
```

DB field name is `password_digest` as required by bcrypt gem

Answer (score 1):

The `password` attribute is only used to set or update the `password_digest`.

`password` is not stored in DB. So when you fetch a user from DB and initialize a user instance, the `password` attribute will always be blank.

```
@user.reload
@user.password # => nil
Password.new(@user.password) # => error because password is nil
```

Your test should look like this:

```
it "should hash a user's password" do
  password = "my grand secret"
  user = User.create!(password: password)
  expect(user.password_digest).to eq(BCrypt::Password.create(password))
end
```